# My first for loop in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql

```
/*alter table schematics
add type_id NUMBER;*/

begin

for i in  (
select a.id,
       substr(a.key,
              instr(a.key, '|') + 1,
              (instr(a.key, '|', 1, 2) -
              (instr(a.key, '|', 1, 1) + 1))) TYPE_ID
  from schematics a)
  loop 
    update schematics
    set type_id = TYPE_ID;
  end loop;
)
end
```

Hey guys, can you help me out?
TYPE_ID gives me a bunch of IDs and I want to store them in my newly created column using a for loop..first time using a for in sql, no idea how to do it.
Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no such thing as a for loop in SQL. Only in procedural extensions some DBMS provide loops are possible. But these language vary. So it would be necessary to know on what DBMS you're on, to help you. Please edit the question and include the DBMS you're using in the tags. And you most likely don't need a loop anyway. Looks like this can be done with set operations too. (And you don't have a `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE`, that is, every row is updated. Is that intentional?)

Comment: That would be Oracle.Are you sure about that? Googling "SQL For Loop" does show results and examples!

Comment: Yes I'm sure. The results are for various of those procedural extensions I mentioned. For Oracle it's PL/SQL.

Comment: The FOR Loop in Oracle/PLSQL is theexample iI've been trying to use actually , without sucess so far.

Comment: Your loop seems syntactically OK. But you don't use `i` in the body. And in this kind of loop `i` would be a record with a row from the result of the query. It's not a number, what you possibly believe as your naming suggests.

Comment: So "i" represents each of the rows the query finds correct?

Comment: Yes. For example you could use `i.id` in the body of your loop to access the `id` of the current record.

Comment: So by acessing the current id with your change, it should work right, everything else looked ok, was missing that part though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to update the newly created column with a value calculated from another column. This is usually done with a mere update:

```
update schematics
set type_id = 
  substr(key,
         instr(key, '|') + 1, 
         instr(key, '|', 1, 2) - instr(key, '|', 1, 1) - 1);
```

If you want to do the same in PL/SQL with a loop for every single record, you'd select the key and the calculated value to use both for the update. But that seems like overkill.

```
begin
  for rec in
  (
    select distinct 
      key,
      substr(key,
             instr(key, '|') + 1, 
             instr(key, '|', 1, 2) - instr(key, '|', 1, 1) - 1) as type_id
    from schematics
  ) loop 
    update schematics
    set type_id = rec.type_id
    where key = rec.key;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I'd guessed, instead of `key` (which seems to encode a type of some sort) `id` could be used to identify the row.

Comment: @sticky bit: Yes we could, but as this formula is per `key`, it makes more sense to use that. However, I had an error in my query (I didn't select `key`) and I've added `distinct` so that I don't update the same rows multiple again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a for loop. Furthermore there are no loops in pure SQL... Just because you generally don't need them. There are loops in procedural extensions such as PL/SQL (Oracle) or T/SQL (SQL server) but they really do not solve your problem.

Just use a simple `update`

```
update schematics set type_id = substr(akey,
              instr(key, '|') + 1,
              (instr(key, '|', 1, 2) -
              (instr(key, '|', 1, 1) + 1)))
```

(Maybe a `where` clause could be required later)

Comment: Will the update alone store all the values I find in the new column? I feel I would need to create one row at the time as (but that's just me, I'm very inexperienced in SQL :) )

Comment: @PhilipBSS I am not sure to understand what you mean. Anyway, it won't create new record...as the name of the `update` command suggests. You should test this on a limited set of rows ar on a test table  to check if it does what you want.

Comment: @PhilipBSS: You'll probably also need a `TO_NUMBER()` here if type id is a `NUMBER`. Like `SET TYPE_ID = TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR...)`